# How do I get rid of the old Minecraft launcher?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I have a problem where my launcher isn't the newest one on my PC... I have the old one and it wasn't really an issue for me until I tried to download a shader pack and couldn't do it. Does anyone know how to get the new launcher? I've been trying to solve this problem for around a year now and I can't find anyone who has the same issue as me. I can still play 1.16.4, but on the launcher there's an article about 1.11.2 being the newest update.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the newest Minecraft launcher from the official Minecraft website here: https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download

Comment: I've uninstalled minecraft and reinstalled the link you provided but it's still the same old one.

Comment: It sounds like you might not have completely uninstalled the old launcher or you are using the wrong shortcut. On Windows by default, the launcher is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Minecraft Launcher`. Try finding this install folder and opening MinecraftLauncher.exe directly.

Comment: I uninstalled again and made sure that it was completely gone, then reinstalled with your link but it's still the old one. I also made sure my shortcut was right and it was.